# How to encode a categorical variable (series) in the data frame in Python?

Tags: python, join, dictionary, merge, pandas

I have a dictionary of the following form:

```
{CA: California, NV: Nevada, TX: Texas}
```

I want to transform my data frame

```
{
 'state':['California', 'California, 'Texas', 'Nevada', 'Texas],
 'var':[100,200,300,400, 500]
}
```

into

```
{
 'state':['CA','CA','TX','NV','TX'],
 'var':[100,200,300,400,500]
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reversed the keys and values in your dict then you can just use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
# to swap the keys and values:
new_map = dict (zip(my_dict.values(),my_dict.keys()))
```

then call map:

```
df.state = df.state.map(new_map)
```

This assumes that your keys are present in the map, if not you will get a `KeyError` raised

So create dataframe:

```
In [12]:

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'state':['California', 'California', 'Texas', 'Nevada', 'Texas'],
 'var':[100,200,300,400, 500]
})

df
Out[12]:
        state  var
0  California  100
1  California  200
2       Texas  300
3      Nevada  400
4       Texas  500

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

your dict:

```
my_dict = {'CA': 'California', 'NV': 'Nevada', 'TX': 'Texas'}
```

reverse the keys and values

```
new_dict = dict(zip(my_dict.values(), my_dict.keys()))
```

now call map to perform the lookup and assign back to state:

```
In [13]:

df.state = df.state.map(new_dict)
df
Out[13]:
  state  var
0    CA  100
1    CA  200
2    TX  300
3    NV  400
4    TX  500

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

If you are worried that some values may not exist then you can use `get` on the dict so that it handles the `KeyError` and assigns `None` as a value:

setup a new df with 'New York'

```
In [19]:

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'state':['California', 'California', 'Texas', 'Nevada', 'Texas', 'New York'],
 'var':[100,200,300,400, 500, 600]
})
df
Out[19]:
        state  var
0  California  100
1  California  200
2       Texas  300
3      Nevada  400
4       Texas  500
5    New York  600

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now call `get` instead:

```
In [25]:

df.state = df.state.map(lambda x: new_dict.get(x))
df
Out[25]:
  state  var
0    CA  100
1    CA  200
2    TX  300
3    NV  400
4    TX  500
5  None  600

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I also have some states which are not present in the dictionary. If I apply map(), the corresponding values in the new series are missing. Can I somehow specify that I want to apply identity function for the values not present in the dictionary, i.e. leave them as is?

Comment: @P.Escondido so for above example because New York was not in the dict you want it to stay as New York is that correct? You could create a function that did a map lookup, if the key was not there then do nothing, or you could filter which values in the dataframe to assign to, only those which are present in the dict and convert those.

Comment: Exactly! how would I do that?

Comment: @P.Escondido my answer addresses that by using `get` instead.